# For $p$ prime, every prime divisor of $p!+1$ is greater than $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

I am not sure how to start this queston. Could you give me some hint?

Show that for any prime number $p$, every prime divisor of $p!+1$ is greater than $p$.

Thanks

Comment: The assumption that $p$ is a prime is unnecessary.  See this earlier Question [Every prime divisor of $n! + 1$ is an odd integer greater than $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483516/every-prime-divisor-of-n-1-is-an-odd-integer-greater-than-n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you start by assuming that there is a prime divisor which is less than or equal to $p$ and try to show contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that all primes less than or equal to $p$ divide $p!$. Therefore, they cannot also divide $p!+1$. Therefore, $p!+1$ can be represented as a product of primes which are all greater than $p$. This is actually one of the nice proofs showing that there are infinitely many primes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint: If $q$ is any prime (in fact, any positive number) less than or equal to $p,$ and you divide $p!+1$ by $q,$ what is the remainder?

Answer (score 1):

the key idea here is that any two consecutive integers are coprimes: for any positive integer $n$ we have: $(n,n+1)=1$.

Thus, $p!+1$ and $p!$ have no common divisor (apart from $1$). But all primes less than $p$ are (by the definition of the factorial) divisors of $p!$ thus none of them can be a divisor of $p!+1$.

Thus: the least prime divisor of $p!+1$ must necessarily be greater than $p$.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint.** If $q\leq p$ then $q\mid p!$